# Modeling one to one chat on firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a one to one messaging feature the intent behind is the following:

There is a unique project and people (two or more) can chat about the project so we can think a project is a room, I've been looking to different modeling structures the most common is something like the following:

```
Chats
    - projectId (room)
        - messages
                message
                userId
                name
                profilePicture
                posted (timestamp)
```

But I've been thinking in a flat structure something like

```
Messages
    ProjectId
    Message
    userId
    name
    profilePicture
    posted
```

The **chat feature** is going to have a huge impact on the web app I'm building, being said that is quite important to make the right desition (I'm sure there is no always a right or wrong but consider the purpose of the chat)

Just some questions that come to my mind:

- are there any implications in performance by using a flat structure?
- what are the advantages of using a nested structure like the mentioned in example #1
- which solution is cheaper? (reads/writes)

Comment: I think that this **[database schema](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3KwKQddPoo&list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb&index=3)** can help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are befenits from both the solutions you proposed. Let's dive into them:

- **performance**: they are pretty similar from this point of view. In fact, if you want to get a chat from Firestore, in the second case simply make a query for the messages of a particular chat and parse the required information from the first document you receive (since in each message you have the userID, name, profilePicture, etc ...). With the first approach this operation is straightforward since you already asking for a *Chat* document.
- **structure**: the first solution is the one that I prefer because it's clear what it does and since Firestore is schemaless it enforces a clear design. With the second approach you are basically flattening your DB but you are also exposing your messages to privacy issues. In fact, setting up rules in the first case is pretty straightforward, simply let the users access only the chats they are involved in. But in this case, all the users can, *"possibly"*, read each other messages which should not be something which you want.
- **cost**: this basically depends on what you will do with these documents. In fact, the cost of Firestore either depended on the number of documents *read/written* but also on the amount of data you store. Here, the first solution is clearly better since you are not adding redundancy for fields like profilePicture, name, userID, etc ... This fields logically belong to the Chat entity, and not to its messages.

I hope this helps since properly setting up a database is vital for any good project.